# Can't figure out why I am getting bad out put from my reverse function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I have created this simple program to reverse the order of my array using pointers.  I have created the same type of program using JAVA however, I feel like the pointer are giving me a problem.

Error Description:

My error is coming out of my reverse function.  Instead of giving me the integers in reverse, it seems like it is outputting memory addresses.  For example, 0x003456, 0xx45268, .......; instead of outputting the actual numbers which I have placed in my first array.  Now I am more than positive that my pointers is what is causing this mix up, I just can't pin point exactly where my mistake is.  If someone can lead me in the right directions I would be very thankful.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void reverseArray(int *[], int);
void firstArrayValue( int [], int);

void main ()
{
  const int SIZE = 10;
  int firstArray [SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  int *arrayPointer[SIZE];

  for ( int x = 0; x < SIZE ; x++)
  {
   arrayPointer[x] = &firstArray[x];
  }

   cout << "The Values In Your First Array Is the Following : \n \n" ;
   firstArrayValue(firstArray, SIZE);
   reverseArray(arrayPointer, SIZE);
   system("pause");
  }
void reverseArray(int *incoming_Array[], int size)
{
int *temp;
for (int i = 0; i < size/2; ++i) 
{
    temp = incoming_Array [size-i-1];
    incoming_Array [size-i-1] = incoming_Array [i];
    incoming_Array [i] = temp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
{
    cout << incoming_Array [i] << " ";
}

system("pause");
}

void firstArrayValue( int num[], int size)
{
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
{
    cout << num [x] << " " ;
}
}
```

Comment: `void main` should be `int main`.

Comment: You're printing an array of pointers. Thus you will print addresses. You need to dereference the address or just declare `incoming_Array` as an array of integers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void reverseArray(int incoming_Array[], int size) //instead of int *incoming_Array[]
{
    int *temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; ++i) 
    {
        temp = incoming_Array [size-i-1];
        incoming_Array [size-i-1] = incoming_Array [i];
        incoming_Array [i] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        cout << incoming_Array [i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment under your question mentioned, you need to deference the pointers in your array to get actual values. Change your `print` line to the following to explicitly deference.

```
cout << *(incoming_Array [i]) << " ";
```